# git project does not appear on Netbeans

Tags: git, netbeans-8

I am a newbie and it seems to be a very basic question but I could not find any answer yet.

I am using Netbeans 8.2, and I have a git repos with php,css,html,jscript. So I went to Team > Git > Home > Clone repository. I enter the URL (https://github.com/xxxx/yyyyy.git), the userid and the password, and the destination folder. It starts pulling and seems to run ok. If I rerun the same it gives an error that the destination fodler already exists and is not empty. But nothing appears at the navigation or favorites.
What am I missing to access the project?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging deeper into my problem, the reason I do not find the project is because the Projects windows does not appear.

I tried all the recommendations (Window->Reset Windows, Ctrl+1, File->Open Project, etc.) but none solved the problem.

Looking at one of the posts, I decided to look at the IDE Log. It seems that something is missing from my installation. I can understand English, Portuguese, Spanish, French and Italian but I am unable to identify in this language what is missing:

```
SEVERE [global]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataContentHandlerFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:222)
Caused: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataContentHandlerFactory starting from ModuleCL@71dbb88[org.openide.awt] with possible defining loaders [ModuleCL@60bd9541[org.netbeans.modules.xml.jaxb.api]] and declared parents [org.netbeans.MainImpl$BootClassLoader@3c19b8ca, ModuleCL@6dbbf6bb[org.netbeans.api.annotations.common]]
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:224)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
Caused: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataContentHandlerFactory
    at org.openide.awt.QuickSearch.setUpSearch(QuickSearch.java:369)
    at org.openide.awt.QuickSearch.<init>(QuickSearch.java:107)
    at org.openide.awt.QuickSearch.attach(QuickSearch.java:197)
    at org.openide.awt.QuickSearch.attach(QuickSearch.java:125)
    at org.openide.explorer.view.TreeView$ExplorerTree.setupSearch(TreeView.java:1936)
    at org.openide.explorer.view.TreeView$ExplorerTree.<init>(TreeView.java:1753)
    at org.openide.explorer.view.TreeView.initializeTree(TreeView.java:299)
    at org.openide.explorer.view.TreeView.<init>(TreeView.java:238)
    at org.openide.explorer.view.TreeView.<init>(TreeView.java:228)
    at org.openide.explorer.view.BeanTreeView.<init>(BeanTreeView.java:98)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.ProjectTab$ProjectTreeView.<init>(ProjectTab.java:729)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.ProjectTab$ProjectTreeView.<init>(ProjectTab.java:729)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.ProjectTab.<init>(ProjectTab.java:200)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.ProjectTab.<init>(ProjectTab.java:182)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.ProjectTab.getDefault(ProjectTab.java:332)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.ProjectTab.findDefault(ProjectTab.java:318)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.ProjectTabAction.actionPerformed(ProjectTabAction.java:92)
    at org.openide.awt.AlwaysEnabledAction$1.run(AlwaysEnabledAction.java:199)
    at org.openide.util.actions.ActionInvoker$1.run(ActionInvoker.java:95)
    at org.openide.util.actions.ActionInvoker.doPerformAction(ActionInvoker.java:116)
    at org.openide.util.actions.ActionInvoker.invokeAction(ActionInvoker.java:99)
    at org.openide.awt.AlwaysEnabledAction.actionPerformed(AlwaysEnabledAction.java:202)
    at org.openide.windows.TopComponent.processKeyBinding(TopComponent.java:1176)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2962)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2862)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6366)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2261)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4966)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2319)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4798)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1950)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:871)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1140)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1010)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:836)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4847)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2319)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4798)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.access$600(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
[catch] at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
SEVERE [global]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataContentHandlerFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:222)
Caused: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataContentHandlerFactory starting from ModuleCL@71dbb88[org.openide.awt] with possible defining loaders [ModuleCL@60bd9541[org.netbeans.modules.xml.jaxb.api]] and declared parents [org.netbeans.MainImpl$BootClassLoader@3c19b8ca, ModuleCL@6dbbf6bb[org.netbeans.api.annotations.common]]
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:224)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
Caused: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataContentHandlerFactory
    at org.openide.awt.QuickSearch.setUpSearch(QuickSearch.java:369)
    at org.openide.awt.QuickSearch.<init>(QuickSearch.java:107)
    at org.openide.awt.QuickSearch.attach(QuickSearch.java:197)
    at org.openide.awt.QuickSearch.attach(QuickSearch.java:125)
    at org.openide.explorer.view.TreeView$ExplorerTree.setupSearch(TreeView.java:1936)
    at org.openide.explorer.view.TreeView$ExplorerTree.<init>(TreeView.java:1753)
    at org.openide.explorer.view.TreeView.initializeTree(TreeView.java:299)
    at org.openide.explorer.view.TreeView.<init>(TreeView.java:238)
    at org.openide.explorer.view.TreeView.<init>(TreeView.java:228)
    at org.openide.explorer.view.BeanTreeView.<init>(BeanTreeView.java:98)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.ProjectTab$ProjectTreeView.<init>(ProjectTab.java:729)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.ProjectTab$ProjectTreeView.<init>(ProjectTab.java:729)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.ProjectTab.<init>(ProjectTab.java:200)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.ProjectTab.<init>(ProjectTab.java:182)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.ProjectTab.getDefault(ProjectTab.java:332)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.ProjectTab.findDefault(ProjectTab.java:318)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.ProjectTabAction.actionPerformed(ProjectTabAction.java:92)
    at org.openide.awt.AlwaysEnabledAction$1.run(AlwaysEnabledAction.java:199)
    at org.openide.util.actions.ActionInvoker$1.run(ActionInvoker.java:95)
    at org.openide.util.actions.ActionInvoker.doPerformAction(ActionInvoker.java:116)
    at org.openide.util.actions.ActionInvoker.invokeAction(ActionInvoker.java:99)
    at org.openide.awt.AlwaysEnabledAction.actionPerformed(AlwaysEnabledAction.java:202)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:369)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:980)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1024)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6589)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6354)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2261)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4966)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2319)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4798)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4914)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4543)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4484)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2305)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4798)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.access$600(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
[catch] at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
SEVERE [global]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataContentHandlerFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:222)
Caused: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataContentHandlerFactory starting from ModuleCL@71dbb88[org.openide.awt] with possible defining loaders [ModuleCL@60bd9541[org.netbeans.modules.xml.jaxb.api]] and declared parents [org.netbeans.MainImpl$BootClassLoader@3c19b8ca, ModuleCL@6dbbf6bb[org.netbeans.api.annotations.common]]
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:224)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
Caused: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataContentHandlerFactory
    at org.openide.awt.QuickSearch.setUpSearch(QuickSearch.java:369)
    at org.openide.awt.QuickSearch.<init>(QuickSearch.java:107)
    at org.openide.awt.QuickSearch.attach(QuickSearch.java:197)
    at org.openide.awt.QuickSearch.attach(QuickSearch.java:125)
    at org.openide.explorer.view.TreeView$ExplorerTree.setupSearch(TreeView.java:1936)
    at org.openide.explorer.view.TreeView$ExplorerTree.<init>(TreeView.java:1753)
    at org.openide.explorer.view.TreeView.initializeTree(TreeView.java:299)
    at org.openide.explorer.view.TreeView.<init>(TreeView.java:238)
    at org.openide.explorer.view.TreeView.<init>(TreeView.java:228)
    at org.openide.explorer.view.BeanTreeView.<init>(BeanTreeView.java:98)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.ProjectTab$ProjectTreeView.<init>(ProjectTab.java:729)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.ProjectTab$ProjectTreeView.<init>(ProjectTab.java:729)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.ProjectTab.<init>(ProjectTab.java:200)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.ProjectTab.<init>(ProjectTab.java:182)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.ProjectTab.getDefault(ProjectTab.java:332)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.ProjectTab.findDefault(ProjectTab.java:318)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.ProjectUtilities.makeProjectTabVisible(ProjectUtilities.java:347)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.actions.OpenProject$1$3.run(OpenProject.java:200)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.access$600(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
[catch] at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Anyone can translate it for me?

Thanks

Comment: I could solve the problem using the classical method.

I uninstalled Netbeans and all the Java versions that I had. Then I installed Netbeans+JDK bundle not from the Netbeans site but from Oracle site and the Projects window now appears.
It seems that old recipes still work.

Answer (score 0):

> If I rerun the same it gives an error that the destination folder already exists and is not empty.

That is expected. Once the folder is filled with the code, you should not clone again using that (now non-empty) folder.

> But nothing appears at the navigation or favorites.

Your Netbeans clone operation should say "XXX project was cloned. Do you want to open the project?". If so, select `Open Project`.
If it doesn't, or says anything else (like prompting you to "Create a project"), cancel and open the imported project yourself (`File -> Open Project`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer VonC.
When I clone the project, it asks if I want to open and I answer Yes. But nothing happens.
If I manually open (File -> Open Project) the behaviour is the same: it does nothing.
I already uninstalled Netbeans and reinstalled without any success.
I already activated all the View options to be sure that nothing is hidden, but did not solved it.